# Laserprinter "Ricoh SP 213Nw" does not print images but only simple pages

Tags: 18.04, drivers, kubuntu, 20.04, printing

I used this printer in 18.04 and since today in 20.04 via USB on a computer with 8 GB RAM. According to https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-SP_213Nw it should work fine.

- **In 18.04**: Simple text documents from LibreOffice Writer and simple
  webpages with mostly text worked. If I wanted to print an image (< 1 MB) scaled
  to a DIN A4 / letter size I had to switch off the printer and switch
  it on for the next page again. I hoped that the update to 20.04 would
  make this bug disappear but...
- **In 20.04**: Simple text documents from LibreOffice Writer and simple
  webpages with mostly text still work. But if I print images (< 1 MB) the printer shows errors with its leds or the printer prints garbage on the paper. So, it got even worse.

I tried several things:

- There are no useful log in /var/log/cups/
- reinstall and reconfigure all the cups packages
- reconfigure/create new printer in the plasma systems settings
- I tried several selections/ppd: the default "RICOH SP 213NW PXL (en)" and the "Generic PCL 3 Printer Foomatic/pcl3 (recommended) (en)" but the printer does not support PCL3 AFIAK. I installed the ppds from https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/openprinting-ppds-pxlmono-ricoh_20161206-1lsb3.2_all.deb and chose the the same "RICOH SP 213NW PXL (en)"

There seems to be a problem with scaling the small image to the page but there is enough RAM on the computer (8 GB). Do you any idea? I guess that this problem must not be specific to the printer or driver.

Comment: Set up 8GB swap. Read ` man mkswap swapon`. `/var/log/cups/*` should show if cups delegated processing and where

Comment: Is the printer configured properly though the CUPS Admin interface http://localhost:631/admin`?